# Restore a database takes too much time with MSSQL 2022 and MS Server 2022

Tags: sql-server-2022

I use a MSSQL 2022 Server with a MS Server 2022.
When I Restore the database it need much time.

I used the following query

```
RESTORE DATABASE [DBName]

FROM  DISK = '[DBPath]'
WITH  FILE = 1, 
NOUNLOAD, 
REPLACE,
MAXTRANSFERSIZE = 4194304,
STATS = 5

GO
```

Result:

`RESTORE DATABASE successfully processed 4338 pages in 26.871 seconds (1.261 MB/sec).`

On my Laptop with MSSQL 2022 and Windows 11 I used the same query but the result is much faster

Result:

`RESTORE DATABASE hat erfolgreich 4082 Seiten in 0.023 Sekunden verarbeitet (1386.379 MB/s).`

How can I improve the speed of this query or is it a problem with the MS Server 2022?

I tried different querys I found in Microsoft and other forums.

Comment: "(1.261 MB/sec)" could mean a bottleneck; we know nothing about your set up, so where could be anything.

Comment: Sorry, which information do you need?